# jQuery find if closest element contains something then add CSS

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains, closest

I want to change the background of a div if the text from the closest element contains something. I realize that this probably is a duplicate but I simply can't find where it goes wrong. I'm not getting an error.

```js
if (jQuery(".price-box").closest(".product").find(".product-title a").is(":contains('90')")) {
  jQuery(this).closest(".product").find(".price-box").css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="price-box">Pricing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <p class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title 90</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If someone can enlighten me where my jQuery goes wrong I'd appreciate that alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `if` statements do not run within the scope of the condition, so in this case `this` will refer to the `window`, not the `.price-box` element.

To fix the problem, select the element you want to amend directly.

```js
$('.product:has(.product-title a:contains("90")) .price-box').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="price-box">Pricing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <p class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title 90</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="price-box">Pricing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <p class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title 45</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="price-box">Pricing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <p class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title 190</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it changes all price-boxes to red instead of only the ones which contain the 90. I've tried using the .each() and using an else but this doesn't seem to change that.

Comment: In which case you need to work on the specific instances of those elements, not select all of them. I've updated the answer for you. Note for future reference that the question would be clearer if you included all relevant HTML and the JS context you're working in.

Comment: I apologize. I should've been more elaborate. But yes this is what I'm looking for. Thanks for your time and answer!

Comment: No problem, glad to help